# Create a link between sheets in EXCEL

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I am a beginner and I tried this on my own at first. I clicked on a cell - clicked on link and selected the sheet I wanted - But by doing this if I filter my sheet in whatever way my link will be destroyed or switched with something else.

I am trying to create a link between sheets for example (image below)
If I click on `C4` it should open sheet "Payable". Even if I filter my tables or anything on my sheet I don't want my link to be destroyed/switched/corrupted. Thank you so much

[image]

Comment: Right click on the text in the cell, choose "Link" from context menu. In the dialog, select "Current document". Then choose the desired table name from the tree on the right side and click "OK".

Comment: I did that but the problem is when i filter a column the link will not work anymore

Comment: It works fine in my environment (Office 365)

Comment: If you have a full table of 100 lines and you use for each cell in column A  the link function and you change the order of your table (with filters)  it will not work

Comment: @ChNa I created a table, re-sorted it, filtered and re-typed the cell text and all the links still brought me to the intended destination. The ranges the links are supposed to bring you to, are those what are changing? Ie: tab name changes or A1 in that tab is no longer there?